# Build a input with contextual autocomplete and syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to build an input with contextual autocomplete. That is it should be aware of where the cursor is and should provide autocomplete options based on the cursor location. Best example I can give is something like advanced jql query input on jira.
I know they are doing by making the div contenteditable and wrapping all the keywords in spans. But I'm missing some knowledge on how it's all linked together and how to get started. Also I need to do it in angular so any angular specific approach would be more helpful.
If there are any open source projects out there which implement something similar that would be helpful too. I can go through the code and try to understand how it's done. I'm a little new to web development so if anyone can help out it would be great.

Comment: This is not an easy thing. contenteditable is a beast to work with.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, where you have challenges with it and we may be able to assist you with fixing it

Comment: Hi I have not written code yet. I was just trying to figure out an approach on how to go about attempting it. I'm not looking for a readymade solution just some ideas on how it can be made.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is by using `[(ngModel)]` you always know the current value of the input. You can break it down into a word array using `.split(' ')` and then generate from the last element in that array (ie the current word being typed) a list of suggestions. Then present it somehow for the user to select. Uppon selection you can replace the last word of the array from earlier with the one that the user has selected, and then rebuild it as one string.

Comment: Yeah I also thought of that. One thing I was stuck at in this approach is that if someone moves back and tries to edit a key or value or operator then how to give correct suggestion in that case.

Comment: Perhaps you can keep the previous state of the string and compare it for each word for every key stroke with the new value. And just give suggestions for the one that's different at each time.